# Javascript splicing an array just replaces the value instead of removing it

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a menu containing a list of dishes. i want to be able to remove the dishes from the menu, i approached this by splicing the index of the dish id in the menu array.
But instead of removing the value and shortening the array, it just replaces the value by the last value in the array.

In a menu with 4 dishes, after removing 3 of them, the array still contains 4 values, all of them are the same.

```
$scope.fjernRet = function(ret, menu) {
  //console.log(ret._id)
  var index = menu.retter.indexOf(ret._id);
  if (index > -1) {
    menu.retter.splice(index, 1)
  }
  menuService.update(menu);
  socket.syncUpdates('menu', $scope.menuer);
}
```

`menu.retter` could look like

```
[{
    _id: '56e827ba0ec7a8d02bf7747d',
    name: 'test',
    info: 'testinfo',
    type: 'kød',
    active: true
}, {
    _id: '56e827ba0ec7a8d02bf77473',
    name: 'test3',
    info: 'testinfo3',
    type: 'kød',
    active: true
 }, {
    _id: '56e827ba0ec7a8d02bf77474',
    name: 'test4',
    info: 'testinfo4',
    type: 'salat',
    active: false
 }];
```

Comment: Can you show a test case that is wrong, i.e. the input array and the `ret._id` that you're passing in? As it stands, your code looks fine (apart from the missing semicolon)

Comment: Why can't you use `$scope.menuer` instead of passing `menu` as arg? Do they have different content?

Comment: what is the code inside `menuService.update(menu)` and what is `socket.syncUpdates('menu', $scope.menuer)` doing? also it would be great if you can share before and after value for understanding.

Comment: `menu.retter.indexOf(ret._id);` will never match. That's not how you search an array of objects.

Comment: @s4ber neither of these are the issue. I've tried outcommenting both.

Comment: @AndréDion but it does match :/

Comment: @JonasOlesen [No, it doesn't.](https://jsfiddle.net/91m9wy2f/)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
var index = menu.retter.indexOf(ret._id);
```

by this:

```
var index = menu.retter.map(function(x){
    return x._id
}).indexOf(ret._id);
```

The [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will return a mapped array with only the `_id`'s, then your `.indexOf()` can work.

Hope it helps.